# Error:{"error: "unexpected error"} when using http request node in Node-Red editor on Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, node-red

I added an http request node when using the Node-Red editor on Bluemix.
However, when I hit "Deploy", I see the following error:

```
Error:{"error: "unexpected error"}
```

Is there another way to find out what could be wrong, and get more helpful error messages?

These are the options I used:

```
Method: GET
URL: http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1
```

The URL is from [JSONPlaceholder](http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/), a free online REST service for testing.

Thank you

Comment: Can you update the question with a list what options you specified in the http request node?

Comment: Was the error during the "deploy" or later during the test?

Comment: During the deploy, as soon as I pressed the "Deploy" button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recreated the http request node (with the same parameters) today and the deploy was successful, and so was the GET request.